# Why can this step function be a upper bound for the rational function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This problem come from a pset in MIT 18.014 Calculus with Theory class. The specific problem follows is what I copied from the pset.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-014-calculus-with-theory-fall-2010/66e412c40f7af7954e8d9a5494f4b96d_MIT18_014F10_pset5sols.pdf

What I do not understand is the solution for part A of the bonus problem. The definition of $f(x)$ in the problem is that it equals to a non-zero number (less than or equal to one) for all rational numbers (and $0$) and  and it equals $0$ otherwise. However, the step function $s_n(x)$ only bounds the function $f$ for a finite domain of rational numbers. Specifically, $s_n(x) >= f(x)$ if $x \in p/q, q<n$. Therefore, to each specific finite $n$ the step function $s_n(x)$ does not bound $f(x)$ up. I understand the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ $s_n(x)$ bounds the function $f$ but I do not think this approach is rigorous enough. Considering the scope of the course the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$ was never introduced and I do not think the solution writer meant this way. I really hope someone could explain the logic clearer to me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe they make a mistake. They should have set $s_n(x)=\frac1n$ if there do not exist such $p$ and $q$, which would give $$\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_0^1 s_n(x)\mathrm{d}x = 2\frac{n^2}{n^3}+\frac1n\left(1-2\frac{n^2}{n^3}\right)=\frac1n\left(3-\frac2n\right)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Comment: The idea of the construction is to make teeny tiny intervals around all "big" numbers $p/q$ of "small" size $\frac1{n^3}$. Clearly, these tiny intervals do not cover all of $[0,1]$, so there are _some_ numbers that do not fall in any of these intervals. For these we have to set $s_n(x)=\frac1n$.

Comment: I understand your point. Thank you.

Comment: If this has answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.